# What is a standard format for storing a 360 panoramic video?

Tags: video, mpeg, panoramas, mpeg-4

I've seen a lot of 360 videos on various sites. 
I know that a multicamera module is used to shoot such videos. 
But I don't have a clue how are these videos saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that camera software stitch it to single mp4 or mkv file. with special set of included metadata, that tell player how to handle such file. [specification of metdata needed for 360 youtube upload](https://github.com/google/spatial-media/blob/master/docs/spherical-video-rfc.md)